# not able create pdf with image using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

[image]

This is how i want my pdf to look like. but when i convert this html to pdf, the output is like this

[image]

HTML code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test pdf</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" height="113" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" height="113" rowspan="2"><img src="images/mylogo.jpg" alt=" " height="113" width="150" /></td>
    <td height="93" align="right"><h1>INVOICE</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#993366"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using div and tried various options but in the end the output is similar to the one above.

Can anybody point me to right direction?

Comment: Maybe wkhtmltopdf (using the webkit rendering engine) is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with the rowspan and calculating the height of the second row. This appears to be buggy behavior by dompdf in the handling of this code. I posted a report to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/665) (if you're interested).

You can create this same layout without tables, which gives you more precise control. Have you considered creating your header in a different way? e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>test pdf</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height: 113px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #993366; border: 2px solid gray">
      <div style="float: left; width: 150px;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/150/113" alt=" " height="113" width="150" /></div>
      <div style="background-color: white; padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px; text-align: right;"><h1 style="margin: 0px;">INVOICE</h1></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: me too figured the problem as rowspan, but instead of doing td i made the entire thing as a image and solved the issue.

Comment: The output of this html also is not desired one.

Comment: Which version of dompdf? v0.6.0 beta 3 or newer should display it as expected.

Comment: Do you have float support enabled in your configuration file?

Comment: Yeah, I think we may go ahead and enable support for the final release even though the feature is still in development.

Answer (score 2):

Use Mpdf. It is very useful  to create pdf files.

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php